# List of jQuery plugins that are themable?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone maintain a list of jQuery plugins that support the jQuery UI CSS framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few:

Date picker control:
http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

[jQuery Timepicker with Themeroller support](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/)

[Date Range Picker using jQuery UI 1.7 and jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

[jQuery Grid - jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not dedicated to themeable only plugins, but here's a good jQuery plugin collection resource:

> http://jquerylist.com/

Also, the [jQuery TopUp plugin](http://gettopup.com/) is a new on the scene plugin that's intriguing and supports jQuery UI theming.

Answer (score 0):

I created a list of third-party plugins in https://forum.jquery.com/topic/list-of-third-party-plugins-compatible-with-jquery-ui.

I hope everyone helps it to grow up.